# Java readObject and casting with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, casting

this is my first question here as till now I've always found what I've needed, but this time something relatively basic is driving me crazy. So I have this class:

```
public class QImage {
protected String imagePath;

public QImage() {

}

public QImage(String imgPath) {
    imagePath = imgPath;
}
```

And than:

```
public class DImage extends QImage implements Serializable {
protected int imageId;

public DImage(String imagePath) {
    imageId = 0;
}
```

And later in code:

```
private void saveData(String filePath, List<DImage> imap) {
try {

 FileOutputStream fileImap = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
 ObjectOutputStream objectImap = new ObjectOutputStream(fileImap);

    for (DImage image : imap) {
        objectImap.writeObject(image);
    }
```

And at this point everything seems to be fine, untill:

```
public List<DImage> loadData(String filePath) {

    List<DImage> imap = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        FileInputStream fileImap = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath+"_imap.dat"));
        ObjectInputStream objectImap = new ObjectInputStream(fileImap);

        while (true) {
            try {
                **imap.add((DImage) objectImap.readObject());**
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

I'm getting String imagePath=null. I'm sure it's something about constructors and casting readObject to DImage, but I don't know how to cope with that. If I create another String in DImage, which is not inherited from QImage, everything works fine.

Edit:

So I call it simply:

```
    Desc desc = new Desc();
    List<DImage> imagesList = desc.loadData("C:\\collective.xml");
```

The thing is, that the default constructor is called when:

```
imap.add((DImage) objectImap.readObject());
```

Comment: Show where you call `loadData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `imagePath==null` because the constructor `QImage(String)` which set this field is never executed by the class `DImage`:

```
public class DImage extends QImage implements Serializable {
protected int imageId;

public DImage(String imagePath) {
    super(imagePath); // <-- you have to call the constructor
    imageId = 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Additionally you have to make your class `QImage` implement `Serializable` because only fields of classes that implement this interface is saved/restored (just verified).

Comment: Actually I've tried it myself and it does not work also (so I did not mention about that).

Comment: If you don't understand which is when executed use step-by-step debugging when the object(s) are deserialized. Anyway IMHO reading and writing objects via ObjectInpu/OutputStream is antiquated and highly insecure and should no longer be used. For example it is better to use Jackson and serialize the data only to JSON format (not code and data).

Comment: @Robert Source on the insecurity of Java's object streams? And his code shows no connection between the member `QImage#imagePath` & the parameter of `loadData(String filePath)`, so although he *should* still delegate the path to it's supertype, I don't believe he's showing anything that suggests the two are connected (even though it may seem as if it would be)

Comment: Yup, imagePath and filePath are not connected at all. When running debbuger step by step, the default constructor of QImage (the empty one) is called when casting readObject to DImage, which does not suprise me, but I have no idea how to change it. Deleting it results with IOException.

Comment: Please show where & how you call `loadData`, including the declaration and assignments of thr arguments you're passing it.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much. Oh, i spent a lot of time trying to fix that, and it was just 2 words :)